# Does passing new int(71) as an argument of type int* cause memory leaks as well?

Tags: c++, opencv

The third parameter of `createTrackbar()` is of type `int*`. When I have global variable `int globalKSize`, I can pass it as the third argument. However, I want to avoid defining many global variables. So I want to replace `globalKSize` with `localKSize` as shown in the following code.

Unfortunately, `localKSize` is now inaccessible from within `main` function because of scoping.
I have no idea other than passing `new int(71)` to `createTrackbar()`. Does it cause memory leaks because we now have no control to deallocate it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

const string wndOriginal = "Original";
const string wndBlurred = "Blurred";
const string tbKSize = "KSize";

const string path = "../resources/test.png";


Mat original = imread(path);
Mat blurred;


int globalKSize = 71;


void Refresh()
{
    globalKSize = getTrackbarPos(tbKSize, wndBlurred);
    //int localkSize = getTrackbarPos(tbKSize, wndBlurred);

    if (globalKSize % 2 != 0)
        GaussianBlur(original, blurred, cv::Size(globalKSize, globalKSize), 3, 0);


    //if (localKSize % 2 != 0)
        //GaussianBlur(original, blurred, cv::Size(localKSize, localKSize), 3, 0);

    imshow(wndBlurred, blurred);
}


void onKSize(int, void *)
{
    Refresh();
}

int main()
{
    namedWindow(wndOriginal);
    namedWindow(wndBlurred);

    createTrackbar(tbKSize, wndBlurred, &globalKSize, 100, onKSize);
    //createTrackbar(tbKSize, wndBlurred, new int(71), 100, onKSize);


    Refresh();
    imshow(wndOriginal, original);

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

## Edit:

Based on the given comments and answer, I have the following ideas. But it seems to be not a good programming trick.

```
// stupid solution A
int init=71;
createTrackbar(tbKSize, wndBlurred, &init, 100, onKSize);


// crazy solution B
int *init = new int(71);
createTrackbar(tbKSize, wndBlurred, init, 100, onKSize);
delete init;
```

Could give me smarter solutions?

Comment: why not move the variable into the scope of the main function?

Comment: @Mansoor: How can? the local variable `localKSize` must be in `Refresh` rather than in `main`.

Comment: that which you `new` you must also `delete`

Comment: Any time you use `new` to create a pointer but don't keep a copy of the pointer to use with `delete` later, yes you will definitely have a leak.

Comment: Why do you need it anyway? That parameter is optional, you get the position as the first parameter of the callback, and the first thing you do right now in the callback is overwrite it with the result of `getTrackbarPos`...

Comment: @DanMašek: How can we skip the third argument while I have to provide the fourth and the fifth arguments? I cannot pass `nullptr` as the 3rd argument as well.

Comment: Why can't you pass `nullptr`? That's what is meant by optional, and as far as I can see the various backends handle that scenario correctly.

Comment: @DanMašek: I have tried passing `nullptr` and the application crashes.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with stupid solution A?

Comment: @NathanPierson: It seems stupid because  I have to define a trivial variable as an unused argument.

Comment: @MarkRansom: OK. As I said above, initializing with a temporary variable like this seems to be too complicated, why don't just pass the value or why don't just make the parameter type non-pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does passing new int(71) as an argument of type int* cause memory leaks as well?

If it is deleted, then there is no leak. If it is not deleted, then there is a leak. Did you delete it?

> Could give me smarter solutions?

No. Your solution A seems fine.

> I cannot pass nullptr as the 3rd argument as well.

<s>Why not? According to the documentation, that parameter is "optional". Does that not mean you may pass null?</s>

Edit: [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gaf78d2155d30b728fc413803745b67a9b) says it is "optional", but the implementation doesn't seem to reflect that. I browsed a few implementations, and it null seems to be corretly checked for example in GTK, but not in some other platforms including Windows and QT. That's an opencv bug as far as I can tell.

Comment: Windows backend checks it too (checked the code, and tested it as well). https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blame/master/modules/highgui/src/window_w32.cpp#L2368

Comment: @DanMašek This one seems not to: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/highgui/src/window_winrt_bridge.cpp#L274 (I don't know distinction between win32 and winrt)

Comment: Right, and I see the problem in Qt backend as well, as you pointed out. I'm about to create a bug report.

Comment: Here's the issue I created to report this problem: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20159